# iterrows cannot iterate over DataFrame Eror: touple object has no attribute "A"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I try to iterate over a dataframe, somehow dtype is changed.

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))

df 
                A           B           C         D
2013-01-01  -1.328046   -0.545127   -0.033153   1.190336
2013-01-02  -0.549147   0.447161    1.179931    0.397521
2013-01-03  -0.106707   -0.327574   -0.933817   -1.032949
2013-01-04  -0.519988   -1.007374   -0.794482   -1.757222
2013-01-05  -0.739735   1.220599    -1.387994   -0.116178
2013-01-06  0.262876    -0.679471   -0.568768   -0.277880
```

now when I try to iterate over rows

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    print (row.A)
```

I get error

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'A'
```

my current version of pandas is 0.20.1

Thank you.

Comment: Please read the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), it returns a tuple of the index, and each row (as a `Series`) hence the error, you want to index the second element for `row in df.iterrows():
    print (row[1].A)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

itterrows creates a tuple, so try this:

```
for pos, row in df.iterrows():
    print (row.A)
```